# Attempting to use .append() in a while loop to add to a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am really new at this and am struggling with retaining and comprehending the syntax of loops etc.  I have included a screenshot of my most successful (still failing) attempt at this problem.  I am sure it is something really simple that I am missing as I tend to overthink everything!

[image: Here is the problem and my code.]

In the above screenshot, I am initiating a counter at 0, then I start a while loop to stop iterating when `count < num-guesses`. for each iteration I am trying to add the guess to [user_guesses] using .append().

Comment: You only ever ask the user for 1 guess, so every iteration of the loop adds that same guess to the list.

Comment: [Please paste your code into the question rather than uploading images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: After one gets past the obligatory "Please don't post code as images".  You might ask for user each iteration of your loop `user_guesses.append(int(input()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not asking the user to input an integer every time.
In your while loop, you are always appending guesses, without prompting the user for a new value of it.
You can try this code:

```
num_guesses=int(input("Enter the number of guesses")) # this is the number of times the user will guess a number
user_guesses=[] #this list will store the guesses of the user
count=0 # this is the iterator that will keep track of the number of times the user guessed so far
while count<num_guesses: 
    guess=int(input("guess a number")) # ask the user to guess a number
    user_guesses.append(guess) # add the guess to the list
    count=count+1 # increase your iterator

print("User_guesses:", guesses) # print the result
```